# problema com namespace e PDO

Tags: php, pdo, namespace

Bom tenho uma classe `Sql` que extende `PDO`, mas quando defino um namespace aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro ao criar um objeto da classe Sql:

> Fatal error: Class 'classes\conexao\PDO' not found in
>   var/www/html/DAO/classes/conexao/Sql.php on line 3

é como se o `PDO` estivesse sendo chamado de dentro do namespace que criei, alguém pode me ajudar? Sou novato no PHP

classe abaixo:

```
<?php
    namespace classes\conexao;
        class Sql extends PDO{
            private $conn;

            public function __construct(){
                $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dbphp7", "root", "123456");
            }

            private function setParams($statment, $parameters = array()){
                foreach($parameters as $key => $value){
                    $this->setParam($statement, $key, $value);
                }
            }

            private function setParam($statment, $key, $value){
                $statment->bindParam($key, $value);
            }

            public function query($rawQuery, $params = array()){
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($rawQuery);

                $this->setParams($stmt, $params);

                return $stmt->execute();
            }

            public function select($rawQuery, $params = array()):array{
                $stmt = $this->query($rawQuery, $params);

                return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                
            }

            public function getConn() {
                return $this->conn;
            }

            public function setConn($conn) {
                $this->conn = $conn;
            }


        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Altere para extends \PDO

Comment: Valeu aí cara, espero poder contribuir logo com a galera, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Ele esta interpretando o PDO como uma classe qualquer do seu sistema, o que você pode fazer é:

Você pode alterar:

```
class Sql extends PDO{
```

Para

```
class Sql extends \PDO{
```

Ou importar utilizando o comando use no topo do documento, abaixo do namespace:

```
namespace classes\conexao;
use PDO
```

Para continuar desta forma:

```
class Sql extends PDO{
```